# What's the form and type of the three verbs highlighted in the sentence below?

Tags: verbs

A helicopter carrying elite paramilitary mountaineers took off Wednesday for a "very high-risk" operation to retrieve five dead climbers and three others **believed killed scaling** a treacherous Himalayan peak.

Comment: believed to be killed during scaling

Comment: Using three consecutive verb forms in this context is stylistically clunky. Avoid it.

Answer (score 1):

> = (who were) believed (to be) killed (while they were) scaling [that peak]

The first two items are **past participles** used for *passive voice* (with some words omitted), the third one can be interpreted as an element of **Past Continuous** tense with '*while they were*' omitted or simply as a **gerund** in the adverbial clause '*at/while scaling*' with 'at/while' omitted.